# Selenium throws "NoSuchMethodError" when run on Java web project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jakarta-ee, nosuchmethoderror

I have written some logic with the Selenium library in Java to do some simple web scraping (The logic is not important for this question) that works when run from a simple test file's main() function within my Java Web project. When I try to move this logic code or even just call this code from either my actual servlets or JSP files, the server crashes with this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.usingFirefoxBinary(GeckoDriverService.java:108)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
at scraping.OneCardScraper.<init>(OneCardScraper.java:41)
at org.apache.jsp.Home_jsp._jspService(Home_jsp.java:212)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error is pointing to this line: `driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

What am I doing wrong here?

I am very confused as to why the Selenium dependencies might be having trouble on a web platform and not on a typical test run as the dependencies should carry over.

**I have tried:**

- Restarting the IDE several times
- Cleaning, Building, Etc.
- Migrating the entire project to a Maven-based dependency system
- Changing the browser type in selenium (PhantomJS, HTMLUnit, Chrome, FireFox)
- Adding the Webdriver location variable to the web.xml context parameters

**I am using:**

- Netbeans 8.2
- Java EE 7
- Selenium 3.5.3

Comment: I think you are running it in server mode which may be causing the issue. Servers may have different environment compared to Gui application.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I think you are probably right, but I am unsure as to how to get selenium to run in this server environment if at all possible.

Comment: You are using a glassfishserver, can you try with something else? Like jetty or some other server?

Comment: can you write your code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically means a conflict in Guava dependencies.

You might want to check this Selenium [commit](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/commit/8c03df6b79831c03bb1f9c13b6c5ee43008ebc03) and these Guava 21 [release notes](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21#java-8). Latest Selenium versions require Guava 21+, and Guava 21+ requires Java 8. So you have to either downgrade Selenium or upgrade Java to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem with your classpath/dependencies. NoSuchMethodError means the class that was loaded at runtime does not contain a method that was available at compile time.

Check you classpath to have the correct versions of all selenium modules and there dependencies. And check for duplicates. My guess is that you have the wrong google guava version in your classpath.